# Javascript error: is not a function(it is undefined)

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the 'Materials.get' is not a function (it is undefined)

```
// Initialize the materials
const visibleTextures = [];
const hiddenTextures = [];

for (let i = 0; i < materialNames.length; i++) {
    const material = Materials.get(materialNames[i]);
    if (i === 0) {
        visibleTextures.push(material);
    } else {
        hiddenTextures.push(material);
    }
}

// Configure the UI picker
const configuration = {
    selectedIndex: 0,
    items: textureNames
};
```

Not sure what to do. Thanks!

How do I fix the error?